# Simplify with a condition

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression, $-a (u + a v)$, and I would like to simplify it using the fact that $a^2 = 1$.

I have tried

```
Simplify[Expand[-a (u + a v)], a^2 == 1]
```

but all that it returns is

```
-a (u + a v)
```

I would love to get the result,

```
-a u - v
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your version works for me, though. I'm using an old Mathematica 6.0.

Comment: Sorry, meant `Expand[-a (u + a v)] /. a^2 ->1`. I'm pretty sure that should work in V6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior your see is caused by the standard `ComplexityFunction` used by `Simplify` (see the "Properties and Relations" section of the [documentation page for `ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) to have an idea of what that looks like). Apparently that function seems to value factorization over number of terms in your simple expression.

You can use a **custom complexity function** that values the number of terms in your expression above all and the simplification you want does happen as expected:

```
Simplify[-a (u + a v), a^2 == 1, ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]

(* Out: -a u - v *)
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought something like this existed. Thank you.